# coefficient for interpolation of data $(\frac{\pi}{2},1), (0,-1)$ with $P(x)=c_1p_1(x)+c_2p_2(x)$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, education, interpolation

**Equation**: $P_1(x)=cos^2x$, $p_2(x)=sin^2y$

**Goal is**: interpolation of data $(\frac{\pi}{2},1), (0,-1)$ with 
$P(x)=c_1p_1(x)+c_2p_2(x)$

**Question**: find $c_1, c_2$.

**Answer:** $c_1=-1, c_2=1$

> *My question is via the answer of  this problem, how we can numerically
>   find $c_1$ and $c_2$?*

Comment: Hint: $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\
c_2
\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I know it, @ZackNi my challenge is very basic, how using it and in last calculation. how the numerically value $c_1, c_2@ is calculated. this is my problem.

Comment: Matrix multiplication.

Comment: @ZackNi Sorry for my lack of English knowledge. how this matrix is calculated?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuixY2bCc_0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $P(x)=c_1p_1(x)+c_2p_2(x)$ so

$\begin{pmatrix}p_1(x) & p_2(x)\\ p_1(y) & p_2(y) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}P(x) \\ P(y) \end{pmatrix}$

then

$\begin{pmatrix}p_1(\frac{\pi}{2}) & p_2(\frac{\pi}{2})\\ p_1(0) & p_2(0) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}P(\frac{\pi}{2}) \\ P(0) \end{pmatrix}$

then 
$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

By matrix multiplication:

[image]

$\begin{pmatrix}c_2 \\ c_1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

So $c_2 = 1$ and $c_1 = -1$

Comment: one challenge is comes to my mind, really why we use this matrix?

Comment: @MojiMoji See what I added.

Comment: Thanks very useful. I get the problem, but main problem is still remains. why you use this matrix? you wrote "since $P(x)=...$ so..." I means why you use this formula?

Comment: To make the matrix satisfying this condition.

Comment: No, I means what is this matrix called?

Comment: The rotation matrix or coefficient matrix